# 'ERROR: syntax error at or near "AS"' for a PL/pgSQL function with FOR LOOP

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, plpgsql

I am getting an error for the below `FOR` loop with cursor in a function:

> ```
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "AS"
> ```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION functionName(custom varchar(15)) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$

DECLARE 
...

BEGIN
...
    FOR loop AS cursor CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT column FROM table
    DO
    ...
    END FOR;
    RETURN someValue;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Where [in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) did you find that syntax?

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong syntax - Postgres doesn't support declaration of CURSOR inside `FOR` statement. See [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE r record;
BEGIN
   FOR r IN SELECT xx,yy FROM some_tab
   LOOP
     RAISE NOTICE 'row data: %', r;
   END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It looks so you are using ANSI SQL PSM syntax. PL/pgSQL is based on PL/SQL syntax (Oracle/ADA).